# request query convert from vb to c#

Tags: c#

this code is  made by vb,page name:main.aspx

when i type the url like that main.aspx?sStyle=0 
it type word Yes in the page

and  if i type the url like that main.aspx?sStyle=0 
it type word No in the page

```
<%@ Page Language=VB Debug=true %>
<%
Dim sStyle

    If Request.QueryString("sStyle") = "0" Or Len(Request.QueryString("sStyle")) = 0 Then
        Me = 0
    ElseIf Request.QueryString("sStyle") = "1" Then
        Me = 1
    End If
%>

<%If sStyle = "0" Then%>
Yes
<%End If%>

<%If sStyle = "1" Then%>
No
<%End If%>
```

=========================================================

my question is how do i make the exact same page using c#

Regards

Answer (score 4):

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" Debug="true" %>

<% if(Request.QueryString["sStyle"] == "1")
{%>
Yes
<%}else{%>
No
<%}%>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one: [VBConversions](http://www.google.com.tw/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&ved=0CAoQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.vbconversions.net%2F&ei=o-acS9HuAs-GkAXwqKiwAQ&usg=AFQjCNFgE3oftd1GEUnOexWIU3FO8lz7AA&sig2=UYoMLb6-X5mK1KzXMOb20A)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the conditional operator:

```
<%= (Request.QueryString["sStyle"] == "1") ? "Yes" : "no" %>
```

Comment: what if its not simple yes or no what if sStyle=1 this code appear

<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<title>Yes</title>
</head>

<body>
Yes
</body>

</html>
 

and if sStyle=2 this one appear
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<title>No</title>
</head>

<body>
No
</body>

</html>


how can i do this

Comment: This code is more neat and compact but not useful when you need larger html for 1 or 0

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@ Page Language=VB Debug=true %>
<% Dim sStyle
    If Request.QueryString("sStyle") = "0" Or
       Len(Request.QueryString("sStyle")) = 0 Then 
        Me = 0 
    ElseIf Request.QueryString("sStyle") = "1" Then 
        Me = 1 
    End If 
%>
<%If sStyle = "0" Then%> Yes <%End If%>
<%If sStyle = "1" Then%> No <%End If%>
```